# How can I use "getElementsByTagName" on a DOMElement in PHP?

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

How can I use a `getElementsByTagName()` on a `DOMElement` in PHP?

I want to go through the second cell, `td`, in every row, `tr`, in a `table` to get the rows title:

```
function getDetails($url) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

    $table = $doc->getElementById("table");
    $rows = $doc->getElementsByTagName("tr");

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $items = $row->getElementsByTagName("td");
        $title = $items->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Although, when I try to run it I get this error on `$title = $items->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;`:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on null

I've tried to find a solution to the problem but didn't find anything. Do anyone know how I can fix this or should I do it in another way?

Comment: What is `$items` variable ? I think you have to use `$row->item(1) ...`

Comment: @VincentDecaux `$items = $row->getElementsByTagName("td")`. I removed it by mistake.

Comment: You cannot.PHP is executed on the server side. JavaScript like getElementsByTagName is executed on the client side. Try to reformulate your question better.

Comment: @mentallurg - http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: then show your complete code. it is not clear that you use "DOMDocument".

Comment: @mentallurg There you go, I've updated the post.

Comment: The error is clear, `$items` is null. I suppose there is no `td` elements in some `tr` (maybe you have tr / th).

Comment: `$items` is a node list, but according to the error message has less then 2 elements. So fetching the item at index 1 returns NULL. I suggest looking into Xpath for less complex code.